# Dar un formato especifico a un campo date en un gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

Estoy utilizando una gridview en ASP.NET y esta la cargo con una sentencia de sql y activo la funcion de seleccionar la fila

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Black" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" BorderStyle="Groove" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Width="956px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientiID" HeaderText="PatientiID" SortExpression="PatientiID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OccurTime" HeaderText="OccurTime" SortExpression="OccurTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AlarmFlag" HeaderText="AlarmFlag" SortExpression="AlarmFlag" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AlarmSeverity" HeaderText="AlarmSeverity" SortExpression="AlarmSeverity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description1" HeaderText="Description1" SortExpression="Description1" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

y trato de obtengo el dato de OccurTime con el siguiente metodo

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int P = 0;
            String Fecha;

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

            Label3.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
            Label2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            P = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);
            Fecha = row.Cells[2].Text;
            Label4.Text = Fecha;
            Grafica_Chart(P,Fecha);
        }
```

Necesito enviarle al metodo Grafica_Chart la fecha en un string de la manera '2007-05-08 12:35:00' pero me lo trae '08/05/2007 12:35:00 p. m.'

Como podria cambiar ese formato ??

Comment: Es muy importante saber que contiene   ´row.Cells[2].Text´, estoy suponiendo que contiene '08/05/2007 12:35:00 p. m.'

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que `row.Cells[2].Text` contiene una cadena del formato `"08/05/2007 12:35:00 p.m."` entonces puedes *parsear*  fecha a un `DateTime` mediante el Método estático `ParseExact()` que provee esta clase luego la conviertes al formato que deseas.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[2].Text,"dd/MM/yyyy mm:hh:ss tt",provider);  

String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}",fecha);
```

O directamente con el `ToString()`

```
fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

**Controlar si la fecha es parseable**

Puedes que quieras controlar que la fecha es parseable o no, ya que `ParseExact()` si la cadena no es válida arrojará excepción, entonces tienes al maravilloso `DateTime.TryParseExact()` y lo podes utilizar de esta manera:

```
string fecha = "08/05/2007 12:35:00 pm";

//DateTime f =  DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime result;
bool parseado = DateTime.TryParseExact(fecha, 
                                       "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                       out result);

if (parseado)
    //aquí va el código que utiliza la fecha ya
```

Lo que hace este método estático de `DateTime` es intentar convertir la `fecha` utilizando la cadena de formato `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` y, si pudo convertirla, alojarla en la variable `result`. Este método te permite saber si pudo convertirlo o no ya que devuelve un valor `bool` indicándolo.

---

**Puedes consultar:**

[Cadenas con formato](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Alan no funciono y sale System.FormatException: No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.

Comment: @SebastianMateusVillegas el ParseExact no funcionó?

Comment: @SebastianMateusVillegas me falto tener en cuenta el am/pm ahí edite mi respuesta y lo chequee en un programa de consola.

Comment: no alan todavia continuo con el mismo error de System.FormatException: No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.

Comment: verifica la respuesta ya que la edité, que contiene `row.Cells[2].Text` ?